# How to export the content of a datagridview to a text file vb.net 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, text-files

Please I have a datagridview that have 1 column (Customer Name) and I want export it's content in text file(c:\file.txt).
how can I do that ?
thanx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be:

```
Dim result As String = ""
'go through all rows
For rowNumber As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
'this gets just column 0 (the first column)
    result += DataGridView1.Item(0, rowNumber).ToString
Next
'write out the string
File.WriteAllText("c:\file.txt", result)
```

Comment: Thank you Dancho,but when i execute you code the content of file.txt is DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=0 }DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=1 }

Comment: @dba2015 .. make it `Datagridview1.Rows(rownumber).cell("CustName").value ..`

Comment: @matzone thank you ,your solution work fine but my datagridview have 325 rows and i want each row per line how I do that?

Comment: @dba2015 .. make it `result &= Datagridview1.Rows(rownumber).cell("CustName").value & vbcrlf ` ..